# Page doesnt re-renders though state changes in redux and props of component changes too

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Can anyone explain how to update state in redux? Specially an array.

```
 if(action.type === 'ADD_POST')
    {
      state.posts.push(action.obj)
      let newPosts = state.posts
      console.log(newPosts)
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: newPosts
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a post to an array of posts, it should be

```
if (action.type === "ADD_POST") { 
  return [...state, action.obj]
}
```

This will add one element without mutating the state using [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Btw:
Take a loot at https://redux-toolkit.js.org/, which is the new recommended way of writing redux. It has immutability built in, meaning you could just do

```
state.push(action.payload)
```